# Can modern CPUs run in SIMT mode like a GPU?

Tags: multithreading, gpu, cpu, cpu-architecture

GPUs use the SIMT (single-instruction, multiple-thread) paradigm where several threads execute the same instructions in perfect unison but applied on different data. This ought to have some advantages performance-wise.

Is it possible to run modern CPUs in a similar mode with all threads executing synchronously?
I would expect that this might improve cache coherence if all threads operate on data which is close in memory.
It might also reduce overhead needed for synchronizing 32+ threads.

The reason for such a program to run on CPU hardware at all over GPU could be the more extensive instruction set, including SIMD, and higher clock speeds on the CPU.

Is it possible or does this paradigm not fit to current CPU hardware?

Comment: What advantage do you expect a CPU instruction set? SIMD and clock speed aren't actually helpful in most of these cases because what you really care about is aggregate throughput, and GPUs are so much wider than even a multi-core CPU, that a GPU can offer more aggregate throughput with that width than a CPU can with all the width of SIMD and the higher clock speeds.

Comment: The other big problem is memory bandwidth. GDDR6 has over 10 times as much bandwidth as DDR5, and GPUs are built to make use of it. And if you need SIMT, the cache isn't going to be big enough.

Comment: It could be done but remember that the GPU SIMT model works great when you have a lot of independent threads, "lot of" here means millions (think of the pixel shaders). In a typical desktop or server, you have far fewer threads, and more often than not, they are not independent at all. So you'll be wasting cycles by not occupying all the threads. Some workloads in HPC do indeed benefit from the GPU models, in fact, NVIDIA Keplero (or something) architecture revolutionized the HPC industry at the time. But a CPU is more general purpose than a GPU. Think of SIMT as easily parallelizable tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupt handling is probably a showstopper for keeping all cores running in lockstep on real systems, even if hardware wanted to try to provide some support for doing this.

Also, it would need hardware that coupled across cores if you want to stay in sync after cache misses, or after all cores do `lock add [shared_var], eax` or something, since MESI will serialize access.  Interconnects between cores aren't designed for constant-time L3 cache hits / misses, e.g. some cores might be closer to the L3 slice on the ring bus or mesh and get a response sooner.

The distance between big CPU cores with their own private caches means latency between them is quite high.  The whole design paradigm of modern CPUs is that each core does its own thing, speculating (and rolling back on mis-speculation) internally, not making internal state visible between cores.  Keeping anything synced, like the issue/rename stage, would be a *major* intrusion, not something that could be provided without significant cost (transistors and long wires, perhaps limiting max frequencies even when you weren't using this optional mode.)

---

**It's not possible on any mainstream CPU I'm aware of**.  Many modern x86 CPUs even let different cores run at different clock speeds, especially many-core Xeons.  (On "client" CPUs of Skylake generation, clock speed can I think only be different between cores when some are in turbo, above the max any-workload all-core sustained speed.)

CPU ISAs include conditional and indirect branches which would make the instruction streams diverge between cores even if you somehow got them synced up in the first place, since there isn't hardware support for stalling so all cores stay in lockstep, instead of what they normally do (using branch prediction + speculative execution).

You might say "ok, then I won't use data-dependent branches so all my threads stay in sync."  But if hardware was going to provide a mode where cores stayed in sync, the ISA would have to define what happened if the machine code *did* include branches that made different cores run different instructions.

---

I guess it could be possible for hardware to provide support for starting in sync, e.g. all waiting for a certain global timestamp to begin.  On modern x86, [normally the TSC is in sync across cores at least within one socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c/51907627#51907627), and apparently with good motherboard engineering, also across sockets.  So potentially software could already do this on an x86 CPU that supported `tpause` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tpause) to sleep until a TSC deadline.

Hardware could also provide a way to keep frequencies locked across cores.  (And voltage high enough for that frequency that no core is going to have to [stop its clock while it shifts to a voltage/frequency combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency/56861355#56861355) that supports the "heavy" SIMD instructions being run, like 256-bit or 512-bit vectors of FMAs.)  Not all microarchitectures would have effects like this, especially ones without such wide SIMD units (many AArch64 CPUs have been limited to 128-bit vectors, lacking SVE).

But I think you'd get out of sync very soon due to differences in cache-miss latency, even if you could get all cores to start with the same L1 and L2 cache contents.  As I mentioned above, stores or atomic RMWs on the same cache line would be serialized between cores by MESI; a core has to wait for exclusive ownership of a cache line before it can commit a store into it.

---

### CPU SIMD is a close equivalent to what you want

I think really the CPU equivalent of this GPU architecture is CPU-style SIMD using short fixed-width vectors (like 256-bit vectors of 8x 32-bit elements or 32x 8-bit elements, or whatever, depending on the instruction).  Like x86 [`paddb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq) (Packed ADD Bytes); the machine code is only fetched and decoded once by the front-end, and it's a single uop tracked by the ReOrder Buffer and Scheduler.  It only turns into 32 separate ADD operations in the execution unit, writing one vector register of results.  I think this is like having multiple simple pipelines in a GPU run the same math instruction.  GPU loads can use different pointers in each "thread" so they're more like CPU-SIMD gather / scatter instructions, but for ALU operations the end result is pretty similar.

- [CPU SIMD vs GPU SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333815/cpu-simd-vs-gpu-simd)
- [CPU and GPU differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681920/cpu-and-gpu-differences)